# Span doesn't resize even with overflow wrap and height auto

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't really know how to best summarize this problem. I am working on a project for school and i have run into a problem: i have a message area where all the contacts' messages are grouped and they appear which looks like this:

```
<div id="messages">
  <div class="message-area" id="some_contact">
    <span> <span class="sent-message"> a message </span> </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, the elements with the sent-message class have a max-width of 400px and both the span elements have overflow-wrap: break-word, but if i send a message longer than 400px, the first span doesn't resize. I will the whole code as i don't know where the problem is.

```css
    @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900");
    @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900");


    // root variables
    :root {
        --ion-color-white: #FFFFFF;
        --ion-color-primary: #B5AA9D;
        --ion-color-light: #B5AA9D;
        --ion-color-medium: #56606F;
    }
    ::placeholder {
        color: rgba(181, 170, 157, 0.5);
        user-select: none;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 10px;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #6E7E8E;
    }


    // general element styling
    * {
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        color: var(--ion-color-light);
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: #7C90A0;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1.2fr 4fr;
        color: #434558;
    }
    ion-icon {
        pointer-events: none;
    }




    // contacts section of the page
    #contacts {
        grid-column: 1 / span 1;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 100vh;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 11vh 5vh 1fr 8vh;
        border: 3px solid #363847;
    }

    #contact-header {
        grid-row: 1 / span 1;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: #434558;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        border-style: none none solid none;
        border-color: #363847;
    }

    #search-contact {
        grid-row: 2 / span 1;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background-color: #474B5C;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: center;
    }
    #search-contact-box {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: #434558;
        height: 30px;
        width: 263px;
        margin: 0 5px 0 7px;
        border-radius: 7px;
    }
    #search-contact-box > span {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 0 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #search-contact-box > input {
        background-color: transparent;
        border-style: none;
        outline: none;
        width: 222px;
    }
    #add-contact {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #contact-list {
        grid-row: 3 / span 1;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-style: solid none none none;
        border-color: #363847;
        background-color: #4E5166;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }
    .contact {
        width: 100%;
        height: 60px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0;
        border-style: none;
        background-color: transparent;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .contact:hover {
        background-color: #4F5867;
    }
    .focused-contact {
        background-color: #56606F;
    }
    .focused-contact:hover {
        background-color: #56606F;
    }
    .contact > p {
        margin: 70px;
    }
    .hr {
        margin: 0;
        width: 98%;
        align-self: center;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #474B5C;
    }

    #profile {
        grid-row: 4 / span 1;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background-color: #434857;
        border-style: solid none none none;
        border-color: #363847;
    }




    // chat section of the page
    #chat {
        grid-column: 2 / span 1;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 11vh 1fr 8vh;
        height: 100vh;
        border-style: solid solid solid none;
        border-width: 3px;
        border-color: #363847;
    }

    // pfp and name
    #chat-header {
        grid-row: 1 / span 1;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: #4F5867;
        font-size: 22px;
        border-style: none none solid none;
        border-color: #363847;
    }
    /* #contact-image {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 8vh;
        height: 8vh;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 3vh;
    }
    #contact-image > img {
        height: 8vh;
    }
    #contact-image-overlay {
        position: absolute;
        height: 9vh;
        width: 15vh;
        background: radial-gradient(circle, #0000 4vh, #5B6276 0px 100px);
    } */
    #contact-name {
        position: absolute;
        left: 410px;
    }

    // actual messages
    #messages {
        grid-row: 2 / span 1;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .message-area {
        display: none;
    }
    .active-message-area {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 0;
        height: calc(100vh - 19vh);
        max-height: calc(100vh - 19vh);
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .message-area > span {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        min-height: 29px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: transparent;
        height: auto;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
    }
    .sent-message {
        position: relative;
        align-self: flex-end;
        width: auto;
        padding: 0 8px 0 7px;
        padding: calc(100vh / 352) calc(100vw / 136.6);
        border-radius: 25px;
        background-color: #606C7B;
        max-width: 400px;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
    }
    .recieved-message {
        position: relative;
        align-self: flex-start;
        width: auto;
        padding: 0 8px 0 7px;
        padding: calc(100vh / 352) calc(100vw / 136.6);
        border-radius: 25px;
        background-color: #4F5867;
        max-width: 400px;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
    }

    // the bar with messaging functions
    #message-bar {
        grid-row: 3 / span 1;
        background-color: #56606F;
        border-style: solid none none none;
        border-color: #363847;
        display: none;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: center;
    }
    #attach {
        width: 38px;
        height: 38px;
        background-color: #7C90A0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin: 0 20px 0 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #paperclip {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
    }
    #send-message-box {
        width: 912px;
        height: 38px;
        background-color: #606C7B;
        border: 0px solid #4F5867;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 0 0 0 14px;
        outline: none;
    }
    #send {
        width: 38px;
        height: 38px;
        background-color: #7C90A0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin: 0 10px 0 20px;
        padding-left: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #send-arrow {
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
    }




    // add contact overlay
    #add-contact-overlay {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        margin: 0;
        inset: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr calc(100vh / 5.96) 2fr;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr calc(100vw / 3.38) 1fr;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
    #add-contact-modal {
        grid-row: 2 / span 1;
        grid-column: 2 / span 1;
        position: absolute;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
    }
    #add-contact-modal-content {
        background-color: rgba(67, 69, 88, 0);
        margin: 0;
        padding: calc(100vh / 100.57) calc(100vw / 68.3) 0 calc(100vw / 68.3);
        border: calc(100vh / 352) solid rgba(8, 8, 15, 0);
        border-radius: calc(100vh / 70.4);
        width: calc(100vw / 3.4);
        height: auto;
    }
    #close-modal {
        position: absolute;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        top: 14px;
        right: 14px;
        font-size: calc(100vh / 25.14);
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: transparent;
        border-style: none;
        width: calc(100vh / 28);
        height: calc(100vh / 28);
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        user-select: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #add-contact-modal-title {
        font-size: calc(100vh / 28.16);
        padding: calc(100vh / 70.4) 0 calc(100vh / 70.4) 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #add-contact-modal-input {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: calc(100vw / 5.46);
        height: calc(100vh / 23.46);
        padding: 0 5px;
        font-size: calc(100vh / 50.28);
        font-weight: 400;
        border: calc(100vh / 234.66) solid #363847;
        border-radius: calc(100vh / 175);
        background-color: #56606F;
        transition: 0.2s;
        outline: none;
    }
    #add-contact-modal-input:focus {
        background-color: #606C7B;
    }
    #add-contact-modal-submit {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 0 calc(100vh / 55) calc(100vw / 273.2);
        background-color: #4F5867;
        border: calc(100vh / 234.66) solid #363847;
        border-radius: calc(100vh / 176);
        font-size: calc(100vh / 44);
        height: 2.5em;
        font-weight: 400;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #add-contact-modal-submit:focus {
        background-color: #606C7B;
    }
    #existing-contact,
    #null-tag {
        display: none;
        background-color: #ffd6d6;
        color: var(--ion-color-medium);
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: calc(100vh / 352) calc(100vh / 352) calc(100vh / 352) calc(100vh / 140.8);
        border-color: #dd565a #dd565a #dd565a #f00;
        padding: calc(100vh / 352) 0 calc(100vh / 352) calc(100vw / 136.6);
        margin: 0 0 calc(100vw / 68.3) 0;
    }






    @keyframes overlayShow {
        0% { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }
        100% { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); }
    }
    @keyframes overlayHide {
        0% { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); }
        100% { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }
    }
    @keyframes addContactModalShow {
        0% {
            background-color: rgba(71, 75, 92, 0);
            border-color: rgba(67, 69, 88, 0);
        }
        100% {
            background-color: rgba(71, 75, 92, 1);
            border-color: rgba(67, 69, 88, 1);
        }
    }
    @keyframes addContactModalHide {
        0% {
            background-color: rgba(71, 75, 92, 1);
            border-color: rgba(67, 69, 88, 1);
        }
        100% {
            background-color: rgba(71, 75, 92, 0);
            border-color: rgba(67, 69, 88, 0);
        }
    }
    @keyframes addContactModalColorShow {
        0% { color: rgba(181, 170, 157, 0); }
        100% { color: rgba(181, 170, 157, 1); }
    }
    @keyframes addContactModalColorHide {
        0% { color: rgba(181, 170, 157, 1); }
        100% { color: rgba(181, 170, 157, 0); }
    }
    @keyframes addContactModalInputShow {
        0% {
            background-color: rgba(79, 88, 103, 0);
            color: rgba(181, 170, 157, 0);
            border-color: rgba(54, 56, 71, 0);
        }
        100% {
            background-color: rgba(79, 88, 103, 1);
            color: rgba(181, 170, 157, 1);
            border-color: rgba(54, 56, 71, 1);
        }
    }
    @keyframes addContactModalInputHide {
        0% {
            background-color: rgba(79, 88, 103, 1);
            color: rgba(181, 170, 157, 1);
            border-color: rgba(54, 56, 71, 1);
        }
        100% {
            background-color: rgba(79, 88, 103, 0);
            color: rgba(181, 170, 157, 0);
            border-color: rgba(54, 56, 71, 0);
        }
    }
    @keyframes addContactModalSubmitShow {
        0% {
            background-color: rgba(79, 88, 103, 0);
            color: rgba(181, 170, 157, 0);
            border-color: rgba(54, 56, 71, 0);
        }
        100% {
            background-color: rgba(79, 88, 103, 1);
            color: rgba(181, 170, 157, 1);
            border-color: rgba(54, 56, 71, 1);
        }
    }
    @keyframes addContactModalSubmitHide {
        0% {
            background-color: rgba(79, 88, 103, 1);
            color: rgba(181, 170, 157, 1);
            border-color: rgba(54, 56, 71, 1);
        }
        100% {
            background-color: rgba(79, 88, 103, 0);
            color: rgba(181, 170, 157, 0);
            border-color: rgba(54, 56, 71, 0);
        }
    }
    @keyframes addContactModalFlagHide {
        0% {
            border-color: rgba(221, 86, 90, 1) rgba(221, 86, 90, 1) rgba(221, 86, 90,1) rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
            background-color: rgba(255, 214, 214, 1);
            color: rgba(181, 170, 157, 1);
        }
        100% {
            border-color: rgba(221, 86, 90, 0) rgba(221, 86, 90, 0) rgba(221, 86, 90, 0) rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
            background-color: rgba(255, 214, 214, 0);
            color: rgba(181, 170, 157, 0);
        }
    }
]
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title> Melssly </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="contacts">
            <div id="contact-header"> Contacte </div>
            <div id="search-contact">
                <div id="search-contact-box">
                    <span>
                        <ion-icon name="search-sharp" color="light"></ion-icon>
                    </span>
                    <input type="search" placeholder="Căutați o conversație">
                </div>
                <span id="add-contact" title="Conversație nouă">
                    <ion-icon name="add-outline" color="primary" id="add-contact-icon"></ion-icon>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div id="contact-list">
                <button id="Contact1_btn" class="contact">
                    <img src="#" alt="">
                    <p> Contact1 </p>
                    <p style="display:none;"></p>
                </button>
                <!-- <hr class="hr"> -->
            </div>
            <div id="profile">
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="chat">
            <div id="chat-header">
                <!-- <div id="contact-image">
                    <img src="pictures/download.jfif">
                </div> -->
                <!-- <div id="contact-image-overlay"></div> -->
                <div id="contact-name"> Contacte </div>
            </div>
        
            <div id="messages">
                <div class="message-area" id="Contact1">
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="recieved-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="recieved-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="recieved-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="recieved-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="recieved-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="recieved-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="recieved-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="recieved-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="recieved-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="recieved-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="recieved-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="recieved-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="recieved-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="recieved-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="recieved-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="recieved-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="recieved-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="recieved-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="recieved-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="recieved-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                    <span> <span class="sent-message"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span> </span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="message-bar">
                <span id="attach" title="Atașați">
                    <ion-icon name="attach-outline" color="medium" id="paperclip"></ion-icon>
                </span>
                <input type="text" id="send-message-box" placeholder="Scrieți un mesaj">
                <span id="send" title="Trimiteți">
                    <ion-icon name="send" color="medium" id="send-arrow"></ion-icon>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="add-contact-overlay">
            <div id="add-contact-modal">
                <div id="add-contact-modal-content">
                    <button id="close-modal"> &times; </button>
                    <p id="add-contact-modal-title"> Contact nou </p>
                    <input type="text" id="add-contact-modal-input" placeholder="Tag-ul noului contact" maxlength="88">
                    <input type="submit" id="add-contact-modal-submit">
                    <p id="existing-contact"> &times; Acest contact este deja existent! </p>
                    <p id="null-tag"> &times; Tag-ul nu poate fi null! </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
        <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="scripts/manage_contacts.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/manage_messages.js"></script> -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have a live version running at https://konstei.github.io/project/ , please check it out, there is still some javascript that got past the character limit on the post.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `span`s are inline elements. Their size is dependent on their content. You can add CSS of `display:inline-block` to be able to size them.

Comment: @ScottMarcus but i did it in another project (i don't know how) and it worked with `display: flex;`; also, even with `display: inline-block;`, the first span still doesn't resize